# Creating an object with multiple values for one key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of string for example like this:

```
var names = ["sam", "john", "tom", "travis", "jack"]
```

And I need to create JavaScript object which will contain all these names separated by `,` by one key.

Look what I want:

```
var obj = {names : "sam, john, tom, travis, jack"}
```

I'm not familiar with JavaScript. I understand that I need to loop through my array of string and somehow append values to my object.

I am using jQuery if there's something in that which would help.

Comment: did you make any attempt so far? do you have some code to improve?

Comment: why do you even want to do this? You have more control over an array than a comma separated list

Comment: Note that that *isn't* multiple values for one key. It's a single value: A string.

Comment: Why not use use `var obj = {names : ["sam", "john", "tom", "travis", "jack"]}`?

Comment: Frankly, that's a single line of simple JavaScript, but you do not give the impression you've actually tried. Check out "join" on mdn.

Answer (score 5):

Well, sure you could use `Array.join`

```
var obj = { names: names.join(", ") };
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> **Summary**
>
> The join() method joins all elements of an array into a
>   string.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `str = arr.join([separator = ','])`
>
> `separator` Optional. Specifies a string to separate each element of the
>   array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If
>   omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toString()` in javascript.The **toString()** method converts an array into a String and returns the result.The returned string will separate the elements in the array with commas.

```
var obj = { names : names.toString() };
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hLuqnd7/)

Answer (score 0):

jap use join...

```
var obj = { names: names.join(",") };
```